# oozie to load file with passwords from HDFS

Tags: oozie, hadoop2

I have a file with DB connection properties (including passwords) in HDFS that needs to be accessible to all oozie jobs.
I am looking for a strategy to use this file using oozie actions in order to connect to DB.

I wonder if creating hive table to load that file and query them via oozie hive action is good strategy to consider.

Comment: If you are using Sqoop and/or custom Java code, you can set up a Hadoop **credential provider** service, and retrieve the passwords at run time. Cf. http://henning.kropponline.de/2015/05/03/hadoop-credential-api/ and https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server

Comment: But the simplest solution by far would be to upload the file to HDFS, grant access to all service accounts running Oozie jobs (and deny access to other accounts), then tell Oozie to download the file to each YARN "launcher" container with the well-known `<file>` element in each Action that requires it.